# How to display a single quote in success message of Lightning Action?

Tags: lightning-experience, action, lightning-quickaction

I'm trying to use a single quote in success message of Account record action. The system add's an escape character in front of it. Escape character is shown in the success message. Any idea how to display it without backslash?

What I enter: 
[image]

What I get: 
[image]

The actual message: 
[image]

Comment: Looks like you may have found a bug in the implementation. Worth opening a case with Salesforce support.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ran across a similar problem recently and opened a case with Salesforce.  I was told that, right now, it isn't possible to use special characters in "Toasts", which is what the app is using to display the success message.

Take a look:
https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2017/08/displaying-user-notifications-lightning-component-framework.html

> Toasts...don't support HTML at all (characters are escaped).

Comment: Thanks for the answer Shane. I will just skip using special chars until their fix this.

Answer (score -1):

It is working for me. I used the single quote(’).

Comment: The landscape may have changed since this question was asked almost 5 years ago. This answer would be better if you found and included some documentation that explained when this issue was resolved.

Comment: I cannot find any documentation. But I recently implemented this and it is working.